# Mask json values using logback

Tags: java, logging, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I'm using below logstash encoder in logback config of my spring boot project.

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                        "creation_timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss, UTC}",
                        "msg": "%msg",
                        "log_type": "%level",
                     }   
                </pattern>
                <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
            </pattern>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
```

I want to mask sensitive data in the json log message. I tried the below to mask the value of key "Code". But it doesn't work.

```
"msg": "%replace(%msg){'\"Code\":'.*'', '\"Code\":'xxx''}",
```

How can I mask json value within the logstash appender ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to mask sensitive data by writing a custom implementation of ValueMasker

Two components are required:

1. A class that implements `ValueMasker`
2. Declaring the `jsonGeneratorDecorator` in your `logback.xml`

```
package com.mask;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonStreamContext;
import net.logstash.logback.mask.ValueMasker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SensitiveMaskingPatternLayout implements ValueMasker {
    private Pattern multilinePattern = Pattern.compile("\\\"msg\\\"\\s*:\\s*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.MULTILINE);;
    private List<String> maskPatterns = new ArrayList<>();

    private String maskMessage(String message) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
        Matcher matcher = multilinePattern.matcher(sb);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            IntStream.rangeClosed(1, matcher.groupCount()).forEach(group -> {
                if (matcher.group(group) != null) {
                    IntStream.range(matcher.start(group), matcher.end(group)).forEach(i -> sb.setCharAt(i, 'x'));
                }
            });
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object mask(JsonStreamContext context, Object value) {
        if (value instanceof CharSequence) {
            return maskMessage((String) value);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="mask" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                            "msg": "%msg",
                            "log_type": "%level"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                    <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
            <logLevel>
                INFO
            </logLevel>
            <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
                <valueMasker class="com.mask.SensitiveMaskingPatternLayout"/>
            </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="mask" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Example:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class App {

       private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("user_id", "97588");
        user.put("email_id", "random@email.com");
        user.put("msg", "hello world");
        JSONObject userDetails = new JSONObject(user);

        logger.info("MaskingPatternExample log from {}" + userDetails);
    }

}
```

```
{"msg":"MaskingPatternExample log from {}{\"email_id\":\"random@email.com\",\"msg\":\"xxxxxxxxxxx\",\"user_id\":\"97588\"}","log_type":"INFO"}
```

Further [documentation](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#masking).

Comment: I need to use masking pattern within LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder.

Comment: @Maddy - I updated my answer to reflect your problem.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Is it possible to mention the pattern in logback.xml than in the class ?

Comment: @Maddy - you might be able to do that via the `mask` attributes listed here - https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#masking

Answer (score 2):

There is a more easy way of doing it without writing any custom code.
Masking has been introduced into logstash logback in 7.0 version.
Here is the PR for it.
https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder/pull/378/files

You just have to add jsonGeneratorDecorator and specify the field name to mask.

Here is the example.

```
<appender name="JSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp/>
            <arguments/>
            <logstashMarkers/>
        </providers>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
            <path>name of the field 1</path>
            <path>name of the field 2</path>
        </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ValueMasker` approach didn't work for me. If you faced the same issue, here's what did work :

1. If you notice the `LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder` in the `logback.xml`,  it has these fields called `<providers>`.
2. On further examination, you will find that these are `LoggingEventJsonProviders` that are basically setting all the json fields in our encoder.
3. Therefore, if you have a field called `<message>`, it is a provider and you can modify the content of this field by extending the `AbstractFieldJsonProvider` class like so :

   ```
   public class ModifyingProvider extends AbstractFieldJsonProvider < ILoggingEvent > {
   private final Pattern[] maskPatterns;
   public ModifyingProvider() {
     maskPatterns = new Pattern[] {
       Pattern.compile("\\b[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\\b"), // DOB pattern (DD-MM-YYYY)
         // Add more patterns as needed
     };
   }
   private String maskData(String message) {
     StringBuilder maskedMessage = new StringBuilder(message);

     for (Pattern pattern: maskPatterns) {
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(maskedMessage);

       while (matcher.find()) {
         String match = matcher.group();
         String maskedValue = mask(match);
         maskedMessage.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), maskedValue);
       }
     }

     return maskedMessage.toString();
   }
   private String mask(String originalValue) {
     // Masking Logic
   }

   @Override
   public void writeTo(JsonGenerator generator, ILoggingEvent event) throws IOException {
     // Modify the log message or provide an alternative message here

     String modifiedMessage = modifyMessage(originalMessage);

     // Write the modified message to the JSON output
     generator.writeStringField("message", modifiedMessage);
   }

   private String modifyMessage(String originalMessage) {
     return maskData(originalMessage);
   }
   ```
4. Then inside your `logback.xml`, just replace the desired `<provider>` tag or, in this case, `<message>` tag with `<provider class="path.to.your.class.ModifyingProvider"/>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add the following to vamsi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77375598/8585072), as it's the most efficient.

Sometimes you will need to apply masking patterns along with json patterns

1. json patterns: ones used to format the output.
2. mask patterns: ones used to mask certain parts of the output.

And this happens specially when you're writing logs to files for splunk, along with having PCI/PII information within those logs. in order to achieve that , you'll have to do the following:

```xml
<appender name="APP" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

      <file>${LOG_PATH}/${springAppName}-app.log</file>

      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/${springAppName}-app_%d{dd-MM-yyyy}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>5GB</totalSizeCap>
      </rollingPolicy>

      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <timestamp></timestamp>
                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "severity": "%level",
                        "service": "${springAppName:-}",
                        "traceId": "%X{traceId:-}",
                        "spanId": "%X{spanId:-}",
                        "parentSpanId": "%X{parentSpanId:-}",
                        "pid": "${PID:-}",
                        "thread": "%thread",
                        "class": "%logger{40}",
                        "message": "#tryJson{%message %exception{5,20,1024,rootFirst}}"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                    <omitEmptyFields>true</omitEmptyFields>
                </pattern>
            </providers>
            <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)card\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value><!-- Any property with the word card -->
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)address\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)email\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)password\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)token\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)phone\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)passport\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)expiryDate\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)cvv\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)security\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)txnFlow\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)cvc\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)cvv\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)firstName\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>\"(\w*(?i)lastName\w*)\"\s*:\s*\"([^\"]*)\"</value>
                <value>(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)</value> <!-- Ip address IPv4-->
                <value>(\w+@\w+\.\w+)</value> <!-- Email pattern -->
            </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
      </encoder>
```